# Rank of product of matrix given rank of individual matricies.

Tags: matrices

If A is matrix m by n
and B is matrix n by r

The rank of matrix AB ought to be minimum of rank(A) or rank(B)
how may i prove this?
Thanks

Comment: Pretty sure the conclusion is false. Why do you think it's true?

Comment: Hint: two nonzero matrices with a product that is zero will suffice as a counterexample

Comment: rank($AB$) $\leq$ min(rank($A$),rank($B$)). Equality is not guaranteed.

Comment: On the other side, $\text{rank}(AB) \ge \text{rank}(A) + \text{rank}(B) - n$.

Answer (score 1):

No. The product of two rank $1$ matrices may have rank $0$. $\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 \end{bmatrix}  \begin{bmatrix} 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 \end{bmatrix}$